# Folder find multiple file types - CakePHP

Tags: regex, cakephp, find, directory

I want to find all the files in a specific folder that match 2 different file extensions, .gz and .bin

I am using the Folder::find function like this:

```
$dir = new Folder('/home/');
$files = $dir->find('.*\.gz');
if($files == null || empty($files))
{
    $this->set('files', "No Files Found");
    echo "empty";
}
else
{
    $this->set('files', $files);
}
```

How do I adjust the find function's regex to look for both?

Also, my view variable $files which I set in the if statements does not work if nothing is found. It works if there are files in the directory, but if nothing is there it won't display "No Files Found".
It echoes the text "empty" but does not set the variable.

Thanks

Comment: Probably `'.*\.gz|.*\.bin'` but I'm not familiar with CakePHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that to look for more than one file type, use the | operator in the regex.
'.*.gz|.*.bin' -> Thanks to flec for this.

The problem I was having with my $files variable in the view was that I was using it as the options for a select input.

Instead of setting it directly to a string, if its empty, I just create an element in the array that has the text value.

```
    if($files == null || empty($files))
    {
        $files[0] = "No Files Found";
        $this->set('files', $files);
    }
    else
    {
        $this->set('files', $files);
    }
```